# How can I compute the cost of this equation?

Tags: time-complexity, equation

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsF2E.png)

I know that the solution is what is in green, but I don't understand how to compute it.

I would appreciate if somebody could explain me or only to give me a link where I can understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can replace n with 2^k (power(2,k)) and do a proof by induction over k where the time complexity is O(f(n)) = O(1) + O(f(n/2)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case (where n>1), the recursion is n + T(n/2) + T(n/2).
This can be simplified to 2T(n/2) + n.

By the Master Method of solving recurrences, let a = 2, b = 2 and f(n) = O(n).

According to the theorem, log (base b) of a is log (base 2) of 2, which is clearly 1. So O(n^(log(base b) of a)) is O(n^(1)) is O(n).

***Case 2 of the Master Theorem* says that if f(n) is equal in complexity to O(n^(log(base b) of a)), then the entire recurrence has a complexity of O(n^(log(base b) of a) * log(n)).**

Therefore the overall complexity is O(n^(log(base b) of a) * log(n)) which is **O(n * log(n)).** When dealing with complexity, we can use log(n) and lg(n) interchangeably. So choice C is correct.

P.S. A really good overview of how to apply the master method is [here.](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf)